# Как перейти на другой сайт, не теряя сессии?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Как можно перейти на другой сайт, не теряя сессии, и потом, например, через 5 секунд вернуться на свой сайт? Только разбираюсь в  Jquery и Codeigniter, и не могу понять, как реализовать. По сути мне нужно реализовать авто-серфинг, без рекламных целей, просто просмотреть сайты из списка и вернуться в исходную. Пробивал через pURL - возникают проблемы с кодировкой и теряется структура сайта.

Answer (score 1):

В конфигурации `CodeIgniter` (`application\config\config.php`) найди параметр "`sess_expire_on_close`" и поставь значение `TRUE`!

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, сессия теряется при закрытии браузера. Если "уйти" с сайта (открыть другой сайт в той же вкладке), то сессия не теряется. И при возврате сессия продолжается.